# Comparison of "迷惑をかける" and "手数をかける"?

Tags: word-choice, nuances, keigo

> (1) ご迷惑{めいわく}をおかけして、申し訳ありません。
>   (2) 毎日{まいにち}、大変{たいへん}お手数{てすう}をおかけして、申し訳ありません。

- both basically mean the same thing?
- the time period for #1 is from 1 *afternoon* to several years?
- this time period for #2 is from 1 *week* to several years?
- #2 is rarely used?

Comment: Your question seems unclear. On one hand you're asking about 迷惑 and 手数, while the question body seems to be asking about time period.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two phrases are more or less the same but the way I see it, there is a tiny but appreciable difference between them:

> 迷惑をかける = to inconvenience someone; to be a nuisance to someone
>
> 手数をかける = to inconvenience someone by putting them to trouble, that is, **by      making them do something (often 'extra' something) for or because of you**

You can 'inconvenience' others without the inconvenienced party necessarily being required to take the steps to solve your problem. (Examples: being a noisy neighbor, falling behind the schedule, blocking the road, etc.) That's when you'd apologize, "ご**迷惑**をおかけして申し訳ありません。",  but not likely "お**手数**をおかけして申し訳ありません。"

"お**手数**をおかけして申し訳ありません" you'd say only when you know you have caused or are going to cause someone to take extra steps because of you, or in order to help you. "ご**迷惑**をおかけして申し訳ありません。" will also do in such cases, though.

So in that light, I think it can be said that 手数をかける is one form of 迷惑をかける.

I'm not sure if I understand your second and third question correctly, but (1) can be said about something that happened on one afternoon, or that has been going on for years, and (2) about some situation spanning anywhere from a few days to several decades, conceivably.

As for your last question, the addition of the two words 毎日 and 大変 means more specificity of the entire utterance and more specificity probably means less occurrence, so I'd guess (2) is rare compared to (1). But between "ご迷惑をおかけして、申し訳ありません" and "お手数をおかけして、申し訳ありません", I don't think either is much rarer than the other. (I say these without checking any corpus.)

Answer (score 1):

"ご迷惑をおかけします" in polite language is "迷惑をかける" in normal language.
"お手数をおかけします" is also the same.

I think 迷惑 has a meaning of 'to receive damage'.
On the other hand,  '手数' has a meaning of 'to increase one's work'.

Therefore 迷惑 expresses stronger feeling than 手数.

However latter(2) has two modifiers of 毎日 and 大変.
毎日 is 'every day'.
大変 is 'so much'.

Therefore (1) has nothing to do with time, 
and I think (2) is used, for example, in the case of a greeting for school teacher.

Comment: After doing 3 months of 研修 at a 研究所, is it better to say to my colleagues "毎日、手数おかけして申し訳ありませんでした" or "ご迷惑おかけして申し訳ありませんでした"? I want to self-deprecate so my colleagues can reply "no. no. you were not trouble. you helped us a lot."

Comment: The former is a kind of apologies.
If you disturbed him and you want to apologize to him, you may use former.
In the case of the latter, you and he are equal.
For example, in the case of greeting for a companion on this board(ex. I and you), I think the former is felt strange a little.
However, the former is more polite.
If I were you, I might say this.
"お世話になりました。毎日、大変お手数をおかけして、ご迷惑をおかけし申し訳ありませんでした。(2nd of 'て' is removed for avoiding consecutive same postpositional particle.)